# Create Date Time Instance in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, datetime

How can I create Date time Instance in Magento For example 11-30-2016 5:00:00 pm.
remember this should be a datetime variable and not a string variable so that I can do Datetime operations on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [php Datetime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) object

```
$date = new \DateTime('now');
echo $date->format('m-d-Y h:i:s a');
```

Magento framework also suggests classes for doing that. You need to inject in your construct method this class

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date
) {
    $this->date = $date;
}
```

and then get the time with

```
$this->date->gmtDate();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. But I need to do something like  new DateTime("2016-11-30 20:26:26")). This is working in phtml file but not in  helper or block.

Comment: why it's not working on helper or block? Give more details. I think that you can combine both objects and get what you want. I've used magento framework datetime object in models and it's working perfect. I don't think that this is not working for blocks or helpers.

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank  you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an alternative - the `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface` class provides support for more customizable options like locale, timezone, output formats, etc.